# iPhone stolen, Activation Lock was turned off but iPhone is still iCloud device list. Can it still be used by the thief?

Tags: iphone, icloud, security

[image]

My phone was snatched. Its Activation Lock was turned off and it was not signed in on iCloud. However, I still see my phone as listed among the devices in iCloud.

Since the iPhone is still in my iCloud's device list, will the next user still be able to use my phone? Or would it be possible for them to add my phone to their iCloud?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. There isn't a toggle for "activation lock" as that's something that always is checked. Specifically, you either have find my iPhone enabled for that device or you do not have find my iPhone enabled. Please edit your post to clarify what the situation is. (Or if you need help knowng if find my phone is enabled.) I'll link this to the generic "here's what to do when your phone is lost" article. Edit the post if you wish to have it reopened, please.

Comment: You also might review the security implications of lost/stolen iPhones at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202960/stolen-iphone-what-is-the-security-risk

Comment: can they still use my phone even if it is saved in my icloud's device list? can the next user save it in their own icloud?

Comment: Why not refine your question to explain what your specific concern it. They can use your phone if it doesn't have a passcode, no?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The finder / thief can use your phone unless you protected it with a passcode lock.

If you cannot use the iCloud find my iPhone app to remotely lock the device, your data is at risk.

If you chose a passcode, hopefully the finder can't guess it. Apple does limit the wrong guesses, so the casual thief can't brute force it.

If you can't secure the device remotely, start on changing all the passwords and monitoring all the services and apps you stored credentials on the phone.

- banking
- social media
- email
- work apps and files
- things like contact lists and social security numbers

Going forward, get an app like 1Password so you can easily change all your compromised passwords and limit the damage that losing control of your email entails.

See: [Wiping a stolen iPhone that wasn't connected to iCloud](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/164390/wiping-a-stolen-iphone-that-wasnt-connected-to-icloud) and [Stolen iPhone: what is the security risk?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/202960/stolen-iphone-what-is-the-security-risk) for more tips.

Comment: thanks. i know that if they aren't able to guess my passcode, apple will lock out my phone and may require to reset the phone to factory settings. once they do that, will they be able to restore my data too?

Comment: also, my phone still appears in my icoud list of devices. is it safe to leave it there or better to remove it?

Comment: No. If they wipe the phone, they have no backup to restore. They can't make a backup without knowing the passcode. Post a screen shot or steps how you would "remove" the phone from iCloud. I don't know how to advise you currently.

Comment: 1. i sign in to icloud.
2. i go to settings
3. at the bottom part of icloud will show the device list, which includes my phone
4. when i chose my phone, it shows the serial # and the IMEI with some digits encrypted.
5. at the bottom of the serial # and IMEI shows "Remove Device" Option
6. the most bottom right part shows "done" button.